# Declaration Or Statment expected Javascript/Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**So Im coding in javascript a discord bot and then what happens is i get an *Declaration Or Statment expected* error even if its not needed**

````
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("✔✔ online")
})

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    const prefix = ">"
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    const cmd = messageArray[0];
    const args = messageArray.slice(1);



    if (message.content === `${prefix}test`) {
        message.reply("Working")
    }

    if (cmd == `${prefix}kick`) {
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Please Mention Someone or Put That Persons ID or Put That Persons Username to Kick The User Out Of The Server!");
        const member = (message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(x => x.user.username.toLowerCase() === args.slice.join(" ") || x.user.username === args[0]));
        if(!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Since When You Have a kick members perm" || "You need to have the kick permission perm to use this command");
});

client.login("not showing token ");```
````

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: you forgot a closing bracket after the `if (cmd == \`${prefix}kick\`) {` code block, thats why youre getting a syntax error

Comment: yeah but what bracket and where?

Comment: oh thank you taht dude for the help :)

Comment: Just small FYI, intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents, all intents is now 131071.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong synatax. Your code should be

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("✔✔ online")
})

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    const prefix = ">"
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    const cmd = messageArray[0];
    const args = messageArray.slice(1);



    if (message.content === `${prefix}test`) {
        message.reply("Working")
    }

    if (cmd == `${prefix}kick`) {
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Please Mention Someone or Put That Persons ID or Put That Persons Username to Kick The User Out Of The Server!");
        const member = (message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(x => x.user.username.toLowerCase() === args.slice.join(" ") || x.user.username === args[0]));
        if(!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Since When You Have a kick members perm" || "You need to have the kick permission perm to use this command");
};
});

client.login("not showing token ");
```

Comment: Just small FYI, intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents, all intents is now 131071.